# The term 'az' is not recognized from Run Command Script

Tags: azure, azure-vm

I try to run the simple command of 'az version' that will be executed on a VM with the Run Command Script but I get this error: `The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the  spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

But when I run this command from the VM, that I connect it with Remote Desktop Connection it works and I get the 'az version' with all the details.
I also installed AZ Module in the VM.

What should I do in order to operate 'az' commands from the Run Command Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
> script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
> if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Based on the error message , looks like you don't have installed `az module` to run the `az version` cmdlet.

> What should I do in order to operate 'az' commands from the Run
> Command Script?

You need to install Azure CLI to run the az cmdlet from the run command script from the portal.

You can use the  below cmdlet will install the [AzureCLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?view=azure-cli-latest&tabs=azure-powershell#install-or-update) on windows machine with preinstalled Az modules.

```
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindows -OutFile .\AzureCLI.msi; Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I AzureCLI.msi /quiet'; rm .\AzureCLI.msi
```

post the installation of Azure CLI you can run the Az version cmdlet to check Az cli version.

Comment: I put this line in the first line of my script and it works! thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help, can you please accept the answer as solution. This could help other community users who have similar query in the future.