# Getting errors in azure powershell:

Tags: azure-powershell

when i use in local i get this error :

```
Az : The term 'Az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Az
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Az:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

And when i use this in azure portal i get:

```
Get-Azsubcsription: The term 'Get-Azsubcsription' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

For the first error, you should install az module in local to use in windows powershell loacally and check this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69615140/the-term-az-is-not-recognized-from-run-command-script) given by VenkateshDodda-MSFT

For the second error on portal you need to use correct syntax to get all the subscriptions:

```
Get-AzSubscription
```

[image]